# xpath compare dates in tags

Tags: xml, xpath

i need a expression to compare the time  vs date of the Name   i want only 26052024 so i create one expression but dont work correctly
`substring(/ProcessData/ListInfo/Name, string-length(/ProcessData/ListInfo/Name) - 17, 8) != /timeInfo/time`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="UTF-8"?>
<ProcessData>
    <ListInfo>
        <Name>Date_2334455__3333326052023.ctl 
    </Name>
    </ListInfo>
    <timeInfo>
        <Time>
      26052024
    </Time>
    </timeInfo>
</ProcessData>
```

i want to compare the result of the substring versus the time tag

Comment: i respond myself  i miss the normalize-space     substring(/ProcessData/ListInfo/Name, string-length(/ProcessData/ListInfo/Name) - 17, 8) != normalize-space(/ProcessData/timeInfo/Time)

Answer (score 1):

Fixing right hand of the expression and adding `translate(normalize-space()...)` to remove whitespace from it makes the comparison work

`substring(/ProcessData/ListInfo/Name, string-length(/ProcessData/ListInfo/Name) - 17, 8) != translate(normalize-space(/ProcessData/timeInfo/Time), " ", "")`

Adding quotes to denote whitespace to `/ProcessData/timeInfo/Time/text()` without normalize space:

```
'
      26052024
    '
```

On Linux cmd line

```
echo "'$(xmllint --xpath '/ProcessData/timeInfo/Time' tmp.xml)'"
'<Time>
      26052024
    </Time>'
echo "'$(xmllint --xpath '/ProcessData/timeInfo/Time/text()' tmp.xml)'"
'
      26052024
    '
```

Comment: ty i forget text()